# Image thumbnails not showing and cannot access file properties, how to fix it?

Tags: windows-8.1, images, thumbnails

This is a folder full of JPGs:

[image]

Obviously that does not look right. I have given it plenty of time to load, but still I get no thumbnails.

When I right click on a file, and click properties, nothing happens at all, I get no properties window.

The files do seem to open properly in all applications, but my Windows 8.1 lockscreen slideshow has not been working since I've seen this problem.

Where should I look to try and solve this problem? Are there any things I can do to try and restore this folder to it's normal state?

**Edit**: I'm now seing this message when I try to open properties: `The remote procedure call failed`.

I upgraded from Windows 8 when it came out, and this directory has been working since the upgrade, it just, apparently randomly, crashed out recently.

Comment: Has it been working before? Have you done a fresh install or upgraded from Windows 8?

Comment: @gronostaj yes, and upgrade. I'll update the answer